# How to draw a two y axis line chart in google charts

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I'm assigned to create a google chart where, I have to implement a two y axis line chart. Although, google has tutorial only for single y axis charts. How can I implement a two y axis line chart using google chart. I'm using an ajax response to get the relevant data! If any one can help me with a good tutorial or and example code, that would be really grateful.

I've created a sample graph to get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'],
    ['A',   1,       1,           0.5],
    ['B',   2,       0.5,         1],
    ['C',   4,       1,           0.5],
    ['D',   8,       0.5,         1],
    ['E',   7,       1,           0.5],
    ['F',   7,       0.5,         1],
    ['G',   8,       1,           0.5],
    ['H',   4,       0.5,         1],
    ['I',   2,       1,           0.5],
    ['J',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
    ['K',   3,       1,           0.5],
    ['L',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
    ['M',   1,       1,           0.5],
    ['N',   1,       0.5,         1]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {vAxes:[
      {title: 'Title 1', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, maxValue: 10}, // Left axis
      {title: 'Title 2', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, maxValue: 20} // Right axis
    ],series:[
                {targetAxisIndex:1},
                {targetAxisIndex:0}
    ],} );

}​
```